# Setting Up a Redirection from domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: redirect

I have a website. At this time, I can access this website if I visit http://www.example.com and http://example.com. When I run some validation tests, I get the following error:

There is duplicate content on http://www.example.com and http://example.com. This is bad, as technically they are classed as two different websites. Search engines may lower a website's rank if they find the same content on two different URLs.
Choose one domain that you would like to use and then set a permanent (HTTP 301) redirect to forward users who visit the other.

My question is, how exactly do I fix this? Do I update the CNAME records? I don't fully understand how this mapping happens or why the addresses are even different.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You need to add this in your .htaccess file